# Classes within python part 1

Tags: python, base-class

I am trying to create a python class based on this class. I am trying to have it return the person’s wages for the week (including time and a half for any overtime. I need to place this method following the def getPhoneNo(self): method and before the `def __str__(self):` method because I am trying to use this method in another program. I f anyone can help out.

> ```
> class PersonWorker:
>
>     def _init_(self, firstName, lastName, phoneNo):
>         self.firstName= firstName
>         self.lastName= lastName
>         self.phoneNo= phoneNo
>     def getFirstName(self):
>         return self.firstName
>     def getLastName(self):
>         return self.lastName
>     def getPhoneNo(self):
>         return self.phoneNo 
>     def _str_(self): 
>         stringRep = "First Name: " + self.firstName + "\n"
>         stringRep = "Last Name: " + self.lastName + "\n"
>         stringRep = "Phone Number : " + self.phoneNo + "\n"
>         return stringRep`:
>
> def getWeeksPay(self, hours, rate)
> ```

Comment: What is wrong? It sounds like you have pretty much explained what you need to do. What have you tried and what went wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Is the `__str__` function looking alright? I mean stringRep is changed several times and the last version is returned.

I think the body of the function should look like this:

```
stringRep = "First Name: "    + self.firstName + "\n" +\
            "Last Name: "     + self.lastName  + "\n" +\
            "Phone Number : " + self.phoneNo   + "\n"
return stringRep
```

Comment: Thanks for the edit Lennart!

Answer (score 1):

I see two issues in the example you posted:

- The getWeeksPay function needs to be indented so that it is interpreted as a PersonWorker class method versus a normal function.
- You have some funky characters at the end of the return statement in the **str** method.

I updated your code snippet with an example of what I think you are trying to accomplish.

```
class PersonWorker:

    def __init__(self, firstName, lastName, phoneNo, rate=0):
        self.firstName= firstName
        self.lastName= lastName
        self.phoneNo= phoneNo
        self.rate= rate
    def getFirstName(self):
        return self.firstName
    def getLastName(self):
        return self.lastName
    def getPhoneNo(self):
        return self.phoneNo
    def getWeeksPay(self,hours):
        if rate is 0: raise Exception("Rate not set")
        return hours*self.rate
    def __str__(self): 
        stringRep = "First Name: " + self.firstName + "\n"
        stringRep += "Last Name: " + self.lastName + "\n"
        stringRep += "Phone Number : " + self.phoneNo + "\n"
        return stringRep
```