# Classes in Python and their implementation

Tags: python, class

I am trying to create a Python script (WageEarner) that can import my `PersonWorker` class. I need it to prompt for a person’s first name, last name, and phone number because it will create a `PersonWorker` object using the information provided by the user. I need it to prompt the user for the hours worked for the week and the pay rate. It will print out the `PersonWorker` object and weekly pay by calling the `getWeeksPay` method for that object. I am new to Python so I am not familiar on how to do this.

Here is my `PersonWorker` class:

```
class PersonWorker:

    def _init_(self, firstName, lastName, phoneNo, rate=0):
        self.firstName= firstName
        self.lastName= lastName
        self.phoneNo= phoneNo
        self.rate= rate
    def getFirstName(self):
        return self.firstName
    def getLastName(self):
        return self.lastName
    def getPhoneNo(self):
        return self.phoneNo
    def getWeeksPay(self,hours):
        if rate is 0: raise Exception("Rate not set")
        return hours*self.rate
    def _str_(self): 
        stringRep = "First Name: " + self.firstName + "\n"
        stringRep = "Last Name: " + self.lastName + "\n"
        stringRep = "Phone Number : " + self.phoneNo + "\n"
        return stringRep
```

Comment: First, what have you written so far? What part are you stuck on? Second, `_init_` and `_str_` won't work; you need `__init__` and `__str__` (double underscores on each end). This, is this Python 2, or 3? If it's 2, you should write `class PersonWorker(object):` for the first line. And finally, you're replacing `stringRep` repeatedly, instead of adding to it; you probably wanted `+=` instead of `=` for the second and third lines.

Comment: @abarnert I'm assuming they're working on the same assignment as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18026306/classes-within-python-part-1

Comment: @JonClements I thought I was having Deja vu...

Comment: @JonClements: Based on their using the same gravatar, I guess they are the same person :)

Comment: @JonClements: Wow, they even made the same mistakes with `_init_` and `_str_`, and with repeatedly overwriting `stringRep`. Did they professor actual give them broken code to try to force them to debug it or something?

Comment: `if rate is 0:` needs to be `if self.rate == 0:`, as well.

Comment: We can't close this as a dup to a still-open question, so… what are we supposed to do instead? There's obviously no point answering the exact same question twice, whether it's the same person or two classmates.

Comment: Using getter methods for basic attribute access is also not very Pythonic. Just use `person.firstName` rather than `person.getFirstName()`!

Comment: tell whatever teacher gave you this assignment to look up python **properties**, this getter/setter business ain't gonna fly here.

Comment: @abarnert well - let's hope people heed the comments that it's a dupe, and I've flagged the post... we'll see what happens I guess

Comment: Do you mean you're trying to *inherit* from this class?

Comment: @RyanHaining: +1… Or, better, find a teacher who actually knows Python, or a book or a tutorial. The OP can still show up to class to turn in assignments; it should be pretty easy to get an A when competing with people who are too busy learning how to write 30 lines of Java-style boilerplate for every line of Python to get any of the actual code correct…

Comment: we are trying to figure out how to solve this problem. We are hoping for help not answers. but none of us understand how to go about this problem.

Comment: What problem? You didn't ask any question.

Comment: Learn how to do all this in a sequential python script, then make functions, then switch to OOP and reuse these bits of codes in the class.

Comment: why is this tagged as `python` and not `java`?

Comment: @Apero then make it purely functional

Answer (score 3):

```
'''
This code released under the ijustmadethisup license
You are free to redistribute, modify, reuse, whatever, for any purpose
that does not violate the following conditions:

    1) You may not submit this as your own work for a homework assignment
    2) You must include this license in any distribution of the code

thanks for reading

'''

class PersonWorker(object):
    def __init__(self, first_name, last_name, phone_number, rate=0):
        self._first_name= first_name
        self._last_name= last_name
        self._phone_number= phone_number
        self._rate= rate

    @property
    def first_name(self):
        return self._first_name

    @property
    def last_name(self):
        return self._last_name

    @property
    def phone_number(self):
        return self._phone_number

    def weeks_pay(self, hours):
        if self._rate == 0:
            raise ValueError('Rate not set')

        return hours*self._rate

    def __str__(self): 
        return 'First Name: {0}\nLast Name: {1}\nPhone Number: {2}'.format(
            self.first_name, self.last_name, self.phone_number)

def main():
    first_name = raw_input('Enter first name: ')
    last_name = raw_input('Enter last name: ')
    phone_number = raw_input('Enter phone number: ')
    rate = float(raw_input('Enter rate: '))
    pw = PersonWorker(first_name, last_name, phone_number, rate)

    hours = float(raw_input('Enter hours worked: '))
    print pw
    print 'Pay:', pw.weeks_pay(hours)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Don't worry - If they submit this as homework, the teacher will be confused because it doesn't look like Java.